# Created new custom resource type through the HAPI JPA Server Starter code but unable to make a request to this new resource

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I created new custom resource type through the HAPI JPA Server starter code by following steps but unable to make a call to this new resource type:

1. Create a custom resource type class extending Resource class with two parameters name and description.

```
package ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.starter;

import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Resource;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.ResourceType;
import org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.StringType;
import ca.uhn.fhir.model.api.annotation.ResourceDef;

@ResourceDef(name = "MyCustomResource", profile = "http://hl7.org/fhir/profiles/mycustom-resource")
public class MyCustomResource extends Resource {

    public static final String SP_DIAGNOSIS = null;
    public static final String SP_CONFIDENCE_SCORE = null;
    private StringType diagnosis;
    private Integer confidenceScore;

    public StringType getDiagnosis() {
        return diagnosis;
    }

    public void setDiagnosis(StringType diagnosis) {
        this.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    }

    public Integer getConfidenceScore() {
        return confidenceScore;
    }

    public void setConfidenceScore(Integer confidenceScore) {
        this.confidenceScore = confidenceScore;
    }

    @Override
    public MyCustomResource copy() {
        MyCustomResource retVal = new MyCustomResource();
        super.copyValues(retVal);
        retVal.diagnosis = diagnosis;
        retVal.confidenceScore = confidenceScore;
        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceType getResourceType() {

         return ResourceType.fromCode("MyCustomResource");
    }

}
```

2. After above step, created a provider class extending BaseJpaResourceProvider class

```
package ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.starter;

import ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.provider.BaseJpaResourceProvider;

public class MyCustomResourceProvider extends BaseJpaResourceProvider<MyCustomResource> {

    public MyCustomResourceProvider() {
        super();
    }
}
```

3. And register both class in FhirServerConfigR4 class by creating following code.

```
@Bean 
public FhirContext fhirContext(){
  FhirContext ctx = new FhirContext();
  //register custom resource
  ctx.registerCustomType(MyCustomResource.class);

  // register provider
  MyCustomResourceProvider provider = new MyCustomResourceProvider();
  RestfulServer server = new RestfulServer(ctx);
  server.registerProvider(provider);
  return ctx;
}
```

Comment: Is this purely an exercise to see if you can get custom resources to work? Or in other words: why choose to be non-compliant with the FHIR specification when you could use the Condition resource for the diagnosis, with an extension for the confidence score?

Comment: Yes right, I can use Condition resource for the diagnosis with an extension for the confidence score, But it may be possible we need  to create custom resource in future. because of that I was trying to create the new Resource Type.
Am I doing correct, or is there any step, I left do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to first get the example from the HAPI docs (https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/model/custom_structures.html#custom-resource-structure) working 'as is' i.e. no providers etc, before adding your own spin to it?

Also to reiterate what Mirjam already mentioned, despite custom resource creation being allowable in FHIR, it is highly discouraged as they are by definition not good for interoperability.